# CSS: exceeding width when nospace?

Tags: css

```
#profileWall{
margin: auto;
width: 1200px;
}
```

And then inside it, if i have this without no space at all:

```
sdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasadsadsadsadsadssdfasads
```

It exceeds the width and just continues. But if theres spaces in it it cuts and goes to new line when it reach the width like it should.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
overflow:hidden
```

or with CSS3

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

*CSS3 thanks to @mistabell*

Comment: Or with CSS3 word-wrap: break-word

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of solutions.

1. Use [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp).  Because there are no spaces, the browser won't be able to add a new line.  So, you can control the div by setting overflow:scroll or overflow:hidden.  This will either add scroll bars or hide the long data.
2. Use code on the backside to inject a space after some number of characters.  A lot of sites do this in combination with adding a link for [more].
3. Redesign your site to accommodate long non-breaking text.
4. Don't allow such input to begin with.  If this is text that someone is typing and it's supposed to be normal words, just test word length to see if you have any words longer than about 30 characters.  You could either automatically inject a hyphen in there to allow word wrap or simply not allow gibberish.  Adjust as necessary.
5. Go the twitter route and just don't allow more than 140 characters.  Design the site accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/VEu6w/

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: I may have misunderstood. I assumed you wanted the scroll even when there were spaces. It looks like you DON'T want it to scroll, even when there aren't. Is that right?